# PHP copy function works in Red Hat 5 but not in Red Hat 7 to copy files to a remote samba share directory

Tags: php, linux, copy, samba, rhel7

```
function check_readwrite($_mnt, &$Status)
{
    $t = "Checking to see if we can write to the queue...<br>";
    $retval = @copy("/etc/fstab",$_mnt . "testfile.part");
    if($retval == 1)
    {
        $t .= "<font color='blue'>Copying of test file to queue succeeded.</font><br><br>";
        } else {
        $errors= error_get_last();
        $t .= "COPY ERROR TYPE: ".$errors['type'] . "<br>";
        $t .= "  ERROR MESSAGE: ".$errors['message'] . "<br>";

        $t .= "<font color='red'>Failed to copy test file to this queue.</font><br><br>";
        $Status = 0;
        }

        $t .= "Checking to see if we can delete from the queue...<br>";
        $retval = @unlink($_mnt . "testfile.part");
        if($retval == 1)
        {
                $t .= "<font color='blue'>Deleting of test file from queue succeeded.</font><br><br>";
                $Status = 1;
    } else {
        $t .= "<font color='red'>Failed to delete test file from this queue.</font><br><br>";
        $Status = 0;
    }

    return $t;
}
```

The check_readwrite function shown above works successfully on Red Hat 5 but fails on Red Hat 7 with 
the 'Permission denied' error message shown below.  When executing the function the testfile.part file shows up on
the Samba Remote Host but the filesize is 0.  The unlink to delete the file works successfully.

> LOCAL HOST:  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo) with php 7

---------- samba share ----------> BEGIN

drwxrwxrwx 2 faciledi faciledi    0 Aug 11 14:35 10.231.250.147_smbinput

drwxrwxrwx 2 faciledi faciledi    0 Aug 10 16:50 10.231.250.147_smboutput

lrwxrwxrwx 1 apache   apache     51 Aug 11 14:34 smbinput -> /usr/local/queues/10.231.250.147_smbinput//

lrwxrwxrwx 1 apache   apache     52 Aug 10 16:42 smboutput -> /usr/local/queues/10.231.250.147_smboutput//

---------- samba share ----------> END

Manual copy of a test file to the local host samba share directory:

```
sudo -u apache cp /etc/fstab /usr/local/queues/smbinput/testfile.part
sudo -u faciledi cp /etc/fstab /usr/local/queues/smbinput/testfile.part
```

SAMBA REMOTE HOST:    The fstab file is successfully copied to the remote host using the manual steps above

```
/usr/local/smbinput/testfile.part
```

> ---------- check_readwrite function output ----------> BEGIN

Checking to see if we can write to the queue...

COPY ERROR TYPE: 2

ERROR MESSAGE: copy(/usr/local/queues/smbinput/testfile.part): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Failed to copy test file to this queue.

> Checking to see if we can delete from the queue...

Deleting of test file from queue succeeded.

---------- check_readwrite function output ----------> END

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, the user running the PHP script doesn't have write permission to the file or directory.

Comment: I included the two example copy commands below to show that permissions is not the issues. 
These two copies work on the Red Hat 5 and 7 VM's copying the files to the same remote Samba server. 
The exact same code works correctly in Red Hat 5 but does not work in Red Hat 7.  
It looks like something has changed in the newer PHP version of the copy function.

sudo -u apache cp /etc/fstab /usr/local/queues/smbinput/testfile.part
sudo -u faciledi cp /etc/fstab /usr/local/queues/smbinput/testfile.part